# Зависает приложение RemoteApp

Tags: windows-7, rdp, remote-access

Есть сервер, на котором развёрнуто RemoteApp.
Пользователи подключаются к приложениям по ярлыкам RDP.
Настройки RDP ярлыка:

```
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
devicestoredirect:s:*
drivestoredirect:s:*
redirectdrives:i:1
session bpp:i:32
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
audiocapturemode:i:1
gatewayusagemethod:i:0
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:1
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:192.168.10.10
alternate shell:s:||firefox
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||firefox
remoteapplicationname:s:Firefox
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:
use redirection server name:i:1
loadbalanceinfo:s:tsv://MS Terminal Services Plugin.1.RemApp
```

Проблема в том, что когда пользователь запускает удалённое приложение, работает с ним, и в какой-то момент приложение необходимо `свернуть - сворачивает`, после чего `разворачивает`, но после развёртки ни мышка ни клавиатура не действует на это приложение, ни закрыть ни свернуть, на какое-либо действие не поддаётся, такое ощущение что включается режим `клик на сквозь`, хотя само приложение работает, не зависает.

*Заметил такую закономерность:*

- если приложение свернуть и потом развернуть, то оно разворачивается на другой (2й) экран (монитор), и происходит этот не понятный блок окна приложения (описанный выше);
- если приложение открыть не во весь экран, то приложение будет сворачиваться и разворачиваться на том же экране - не блокируется.
- и наверно самая странная вещь, если `сменить экран по умолчанию`, то проблема исчезает вовсе, при любых интерпретациях с окном.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть. Спасибо.

Предпринятые мною действия:

- установил на `Windows 7` приложение `DualMonitor`, которое позволяет добавить панель `Пуск` на 2й экран, который не основной, думал, проблема в этом, типо приложение не может развернуться.
- всячески пытался изменить конфигурацию ярлыка `RDP`, менял всякие разные режимы и параметры, не помогло.
- в `редакторе локальной групповой политике` включил режим на использование только канала по протоколу `TCP`, выключил `UDP`, не помогло.
  Думаю всё таки проблема с самой `Windows`, но не могу понять куда копать. Все остальные окна приложений `(не RDP)` нормально сворачиваются и разворачиваются на своих местах. Мониторы абсолютно одинаковые, драйвера все на месте, на всех остальных ПК такой проблемы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же ситуацией.
Windows 7 и терминал на windows 2016
Меняю монитор по умолчанию - проблема уходит. Но у меня основной 27 дюймов, а второй 24 дюйма